# Rails : How to load Validation Module in Console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails development and I just developed a partial code to validate a field. But I want to verify my function in the rails console.

The problem is that I can launch my function in the console, but I can't verify my validation because the official validation module is not loaded.

How can I launch it?

Here is my code :

```
def siret_is_valid
  if (validates :siret, :presence => true, :length => { :is => 14 }, :numericality => { :only_integer => true })
    verify_siret_is_valid(:siret)
  else
    errors.add(:siret, "is not valid")
  end
end

def verify_siret_is_valid(siret)
  s = siret.to_s
  if (s.empty? || (s.length != 14))
    errors.add(:siret, "is not valid")
    false
  end
  sum = 0
  s.each_char do |i|
    val_i = i.to_i
    if ((i.to_i) % 2 == 0)
      tmp = val_i * 2
      tmp = tmp > 9 ? tmp - 9 : tmp
    else
      tmp = val_i
    end
    sum += tmp
  end
  if (sum % 10 != 0)
    errors.add(:siret, "is not valid")
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you talking about an ActiveRecord custom validator on your model?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're referring to without specific code, but it's possible that you just need to type `require 'name-of-your-module'` to make the functionality available in your console. That's just a guess. If you give us actual code, and output we can help more.

Comment: @d11wtq Yes, I'm talking about an ActiveRecord custom validator on my model. I just have to fixe a bug and I can't use the form to test my validation. The console is my only way to test it. But when I instanciate my object and after I put my_object.valid?, I have the following error code : NoMethodError: undefined method `validates'. I will edit my post to paste my validation code.